# if (ComboBox1) statement error

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox, selectedindex

I created a ComboBox where a user needs to choose a language.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString == "English")
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

I'm not sure what I am writing wrong. Should I convert the option of English to a string or can I select is as an item?

Comment: `ToString()` is the proper way

Comment: men, use SelectedItem and not SelectedIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

selecteditem is the value selected

selectedindex is the index selected

you have also to check weather your combobox is selecting an item else an exception'll be thrown

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex!=-1 && ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
```

Comment: Aha. Thank you. And what if I wanted to do is as an item. ComboBox.SelectedIndex == ComboBoxItem Is this the statemenet? How do I specify the item. [0] ComboBoxItem does not work.

Comment: ComboBox1.Items[i] if you are not using the ItemsSource property

Answer (score 1):

You need the parenthesis on ToString --> ToString() to even be able to compile. Also SelectedIndex will only give you an index number not the value. Should use ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() == "English")
   {
      this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
   }
```

Try something closer to this:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
   if(comboBox != null)
   {     
     if (comboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
     {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
     }
   }
```

Comment: please change the second statement  SelectedIndex.ToString(

Answer (score 0):

Selected index should be numeric value

so change your code to follwing

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          bool result = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()=="English"; // case-1
            // Or use 
          result  = comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() == = "English"; // Case -2

            //or use

           result  = comboBox1.SelectedText == "English"; //case-3


   if(result){
// Do the resut

}
```

Note: To work case-1,and case-2 you must bound your combo box with a datasource